# Is it right to say this?

Tags: grammar

Are the   sentences  given  below grammatically correct
How  many  is that ?
How  many  cars  is  that ?
How many  people  is that?
If  not   what  alternatives would you  suggest

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically correct but semantically awkward without context.

P1: *There are several people at the convention*.

P2: *How many people is that?*

This is sort of sarcastic and demanding when I read it. A better way to say this would be *How many people are there?*

P1: *There is a baker's dozen worth of donuts here.*

P2: *How many is that?*

In this response the sentence is correct. The person is asking how many donuts are in a baker's dozen. It could be made more formal by saying *how many donuts are in a baker's dozen?*

P1: *Our sales at the car lot showed we have sold 30% fewer cars this quarter.*

P2: *How many cars is that?*

Again, P2 is asking for clarification. How many cars constitutes 30% of the sales of the previous quarter though it is informal. Perhaps a better way to say it would be *How many fewer cars did we sell?*